# HTACCESS with PHP value

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Hey,
I need to filter out requests with certain PHP value in HTACCESS and I cant find how to do that.

The problem is there is someone spamming my site with special PHP value and it keeps my server overloaded.

The URL is www.site.com/?q=XXXXX. I need to filter out all requests like this (with ?q=XXXX) and redirect them to homepage instead.

I tried this but it doesnt work properly (there is a loop).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.site.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why dont u clean out whatever is being put into the _GET value? (using php)

at the top of the php file put something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){  
   header('Location: homepage.php');
}
```

Comment: because i need that value. it's a search value and i have another rewrite from site.com/search/XXXX to index.php?q=. Someone probably included the query in some remote search and I just dont want to access it directly.

Comment: im still not sure what you want to do, i quote `The URL is www.site.com/?q=XXXXX. I need to filter out all requests like this (with ?q=XXXX) and redirect them to homepage instead.`  which means u dont want the get value of q=...

Comment: I want to filter out all direct requests to www.site.com/?q=XXXX but at the same time i need this value for www.site.com/search/XXXX. and i dont want to do it in PHP but directly in HTACCESS so I dont have to hit PHP because I have static caching running there.

Comment: so use php's `$_SERVER` values and check the uri in php to make sure they are accessing it correctly

Comment: as I wrote, I dont want to use PHP, I want to do it directly in HTACCESS. i know its possible, I just need small edit of the code I posted here...

Answer (score 0):

If someone is spamming you hard enough to overload your server you should look at blocking their IP address/addresses or something along those lines if possible.

Also I would suggest letting those requests die() rather than making them send you another request when they load your homepage. Or maybe keep them busy by redirecting to a domain that doesn't exist or something but that may or may not have an impact on them.

Comment: It's not possible to block them as for some reason the requests come from different IPs. Its not like DDOS or something...

Comment: Requests coming from different IPs to overload a server is exactly what DDOS means.

Comment: but this is not DDOS its just some different website which accesses my server remotely and uses my database for search

Comment: If that's what's going on then your htaccess solution will be trivial to get around. Either block their ips (all of them) or find a better way to detect legitimate users. Maybe set a session variable when someone visits and only perform the search if you can retrieve it or something.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about counting "X"?
if the ?q=X == true, continue,
otherwise if q>9 then you know someone is messing with it and restrict them